# How to cast an object to a primitive value?

Tags: java

Here is a literal class that allows one to get a value of a specified type:

```
public class Literal {

    private final String value;

    public Literal(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <T> T getValue(Class<T> type) {
        if (type == Boolean.class || type == Boolean.TYPE) {
            return type.cast("true".equalsIgnoreCase(value));
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

It works fine for object types:

```
new Literal("true").getValue(Boolean.class);
```

But it throws the error for primitive types:

```
new Literal("true").getValue(Boolean.TYPE);
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Boolean to boolean
```

Is it possible to return a boolean value without the exception?

Or maybe I can transform a primitive type to a corresponding object type before calling the method? Is there a method to transform boolean type to java.lang.Boolean.class, int type to java.lang.Integer.class, ...? Something like this:

```
new Literal("true").getValue(toObjectType(Boolean.TYPE));
```

Comment: Why not just use `return "true".equals(value)`? You can't *cast* a string to a `boolean` or any other primitive type, because it's *not* an instance of that type.

Comment: For other types, look at `Integer.parseInt` etc.

Comment: Yes, I use `"true".equalsIgnoreCase(value)`, but the method could return values of different types, so cast is required.

Comment: No, that's false logic. A cast *will never work* because casts require a language-defined conversion from one type to another, and there *isn't* such a conversion from `String` to `boolean`. The sooner you accept that casting won't work, the sooner you'll get to working code, which is likely to require per-type logic - such as calling `Integer.parseInt` and the like.

Comment: I think the problem here is different. You can't convert to a primitive type because by definition any generiic type T is an *object* type. Java is not like Scala in this.

Comment: Although you're headed for a brick wall, it may help to know the class of a boolean primitive, which is only used when working with reflection, is `boolean.class`.

Comment: Java will unbox your Boolean in the statement `boolean b = literal.getValue(Boolean.class);`, if that helps with whatever you are doing.

Comment: `return (T)Boolean.class.cast("true".equalsIgnoreCase(value));` works in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rzwitserloot` already explained quite well how and why you should adjust the casting and the difference between primitives and objects.

I just wanted to give you a small executable example on top of that. You could do something like the following:

```
public class Literal {
    private final String value;

    public Literal(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <T> T getValue(Class<T> type) {
        if (type == Boolean.class || type == Boolean.TYPE) {
            return (T) new Boolean(this.value); // or Boolean.valueOf(this.value)
        } else if (type == boolean.class) {
            return (T) this.value;
        }
        // [add other type checks here, if you want]
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public boolean getBooleanValue() {
        return new Boolean(this.value); // or Boolean.valueOf(this.value)
    }
    
    /** This method is just here for demo purpose */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Use it like this
        Boolean obj = new Literal("true").getValue(Boolean.TYPE);
        Boolean obj2 = new Literal("FALSE").getValue(Boolean.TYPE);
        boolean primitive = new Literal("true").getValue(boolean.class);
        boolean primitive2 = new Literal("FALSE").getValue(boolean.class);
        System.out.println(obj); // true
        System.out.println(obj2); // false
        System.out.println(primitive); // true
        System.out.println(primitive2); // false
        
        // Or this
        boolean primitive3 = new Literal("true").getBooleanValue();
        System.out.println(primitive3); // true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.. and no.

In basis what you say is a non-sequitur. Your question is: "How do I put this round green in this square hole" - concepts that don't even align.

"An object" cannot become a primitive value, and "an object" cannot be used where a primitive is required. This: `Object o = 5;` is illegal plain and simple.

Except.. it isn't. And the reason it isn't, is only because of syntax sugar. The compiler KNOWS it is illegal but assumes you MEANT to write `Object o = Integer.valueOf(5);` so, it just assumes you meant that and generates code accordingly. Just go compile that, run `javap -c -v` and lo! A call to `integer.valueOf` you never wrote.

You can do the same thing here: Write an 8-nested if/elseif:

```
if (type == boolean.class /* or Boolean.TYPE - same thing */) {
  return (T) "true".equals(value);
}
```

The `type.cast` part **only** buys you a runtime check, which is literally pointless as you already just did so with an `if`, thus, `(T) foo` is superior to `type.cast(foo)` here. Even though `(T)` thing produces a warning - ignore it, you *know* the warning *is irrelevant*. The heap corruption it is warning you about cannot happen / the `type.cast` wouldn't fix it.

In other words, get rid of `type.cast(x)` and make that `(T) x` and the error goes away (and a warning comes in trade; but that one you can `@SuppressWarnings`). The code will do what you want:

```java
boolean v = new Literal("true").getValue(boolean.class);
```

But note that the system auto-boxes and auto-unboxes anyway. You can't stop that from happening unless you make a new method for it:

```java
boolean v = new Literal("true").getBooleanValue();
```

Where you can implement `getBooleanValue` as `return "true".equals(value);` of course.

"I do not want the overhead of autoboxing" and "... you will be making 8 additional methods then" go hand in hand. It's why e.g. `IntStream` exists instead of just having a `Stream<Integer>`.

NB: The cast operator is used for 3 utterly unrelated things. 2 of those 3 are about assertions (is this thing type X already? If yes do nothing, if no, throw an exception / break the JVM, depending on which of the 2) - only one actually converts things, and it's primitive conversion: the thing in the `()` has to be a primitive type. You can't get that kind of cast here, that kind of cast fundamentally is not dynamic. Hence, no conversion can take place, hence, trying to 'cast an object to lower-case-b `boolean`' is an error. "cast" the operator cannot do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! The unchecked cast warning in Java is really annoying. I thought that I can use `cast()` operation instead of `(T)` to get rid of warnings. However it seems that in some cases I have to do unchecked casts and suppress warnings.